# How can I ignore properties according to their value with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I'd like the XML created by XmlSerializer to exclude properties if they have a default value.  Is this possible with XmlSerializer or am I going to have to look into IXmlSerializable?

For example, I may have the following class:

```
public class PositionedObject
{
   public float X
   { get; set; }

   public float Y
   { get; set;}
}
```

I'd like to tell the XmlSerializer that when it serializes an instance of PositionedObject, to not include X if the value is 0 (and same with Y if it is 0).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just declare a method named `ShouldSerializeX` that returns true when the value is not 0:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeX()
{
    return X != 0;
}
```

The serializer will call this method to decide whether the property should be serialized or not.

Comment: This answer is insufficient.  I don't see how the serializer would ever know about such a method.  And besides, this is not scalable.

Comment: @Inuyasha, did you try it? I know it works, I used this solution many times. It's not documented, but if you look at the XML serializer code, you will see that it does call this method if it exists (alternatively, you can also create a read-only property called `XSpecified`, it has the same effect). And anyway, do you know a more scalable method?

Comment: Inuyasha - did you actually try it?  Based off of this answer I was able to Google a few things and found a number of articles claiming that this is going to work.  I am in the process of implementing now.  Here's some more info:  http://horacegoescoding.blogspot.com/2009/04/using-shouldserialize-for-conditional.html

Comment: @Inuyasha this answer is entirely correct; this is a supported pattern, introduced by System.ComponentModel/PropertyDescriptor, and used in a number of places. It works fine.

Comment: It does work perfectly. @Amy this is why I wish I could downvote comments.

Comment: Tested and proven. A good lightweight solution, the heavyweight solution being to implement IXmlSerializable.

Answer (score 13):

One other supported XmlSerializer pattern;

```
[DefaultValue({whatever})]
public SomeType SomeProperty {get;set;}
```

Note however that your parameterless constructor **must** assign this value, or unpredictable results will occur.

Comment: ooo i didn't know about this one.

Answer (score 1):

Your class can implement `IXmlSerializable` and in `WriteXml` method choose not to serialize out attributes that have whatever you consider as default.

```
public class PositionedObject : IXmlSerializable
{

  public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
  {
        if (  Position != DefaultPosition )
          writer.WriteAttributeString("Position", Position);
  }
}
```

In your position is a float pair and you might have to use some tolerance

Comment: If at all possible I would always say "don't implement IXmlSerializable", especially for deserialization - it is somewhat littered with traps... If possible I would always suggest 1st checking XmlSerializer doesn't support it directly (like it does in this case), and 2nd using a DTO that fits the XML, rather than having overly complex implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas' way is probably simplest way to what you want. However you may want to consider that technically value types always have a value, and you probably should serialize it. Note that `XmlSerializer` will skip adding `X` element if you were to declare it as `string` or other reference type.
Of course declaring X coordinate as string would be silly, but you can declare it as nullable `float?`, which will serialize as `<X xsi:nil="true" />`, which *may* be closer to what you actually want... unless you just want to make your XML pretty looking, then got with Thomas' suggestion.