# Serialize object to xml using PropertyInfo[] as mapping

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection

I'm trying to write a generic method to serialize an object that inherits from my ITable interface. I would also like to have a parameter of PropertyInfo[] where I can specify the properties that need to be serialized with the object. Those that are not present are ignored. Is there a way to tell the XmlSerialize to only serialize those properties listed?

Method signature:

```
public static string SerializeToXml<T>(T obj, PropertyInfo[] fields = null) where T : ITable
```

If fields is null, Automatically grab all fields.

```
if (fields == null)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    fields = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
}
```

Comment: You can mark a property with the `XmlIgnore` attribute to tell the `XmlSerialzier` not to serialize that property. I'm not sure of another way to pass that information to the `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: @rsbarro - This seems like he needs the XmlSerializer to dynamically ignore properties depending on what is in the PropertyInfo array.

Comment: @MarkP - This answer should help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553828/how-can-i-ignore-properties-according-to-their-value-with-xmlserializer

Comment: @Xaisoft I agree. Just thought I'd mention that attribute just in case. You could check this article out, might do what you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/athddy89%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you would do this using attributes, specifically, you can add [the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx) to properties you don't want to serialize (notice that this is the other way around to what you want).

But since you want to do this at runtime, you can use [the `XmlAttributeOverrides` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx) to, you guessed it, override the attributes at runtime.

So, something like this should work:

```
public static string SerializeToXml<T>(T obj, PropertyInfo[] fields = null)
    where T : ITable
{
    Type type = typeof(T);

    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> ignoredProperties;

    if (fields == null)
        ignoredProperties = Enumerable.Empty<PropertyInfo>();
    else
        ignoredProperties = type.GetProperties(
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Except(fields);

    var ignoredAttrs = new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = true };

    var attrOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

    foreach (var ignoredProperty in ignoredProperties)
        attrOverrides.Add(type, ignoredProperty.Name, ignoredAttrs);

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type, attrOverrides);

    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```

On an unrelated note, I think naming a parameter that contains properties `fields` is highly confusing.

Answer (score 0):

For each field, declare a property such as:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeX()
{
    return X != 0;
}
```

When you loop through the fields, set its property to either true or false depending on if you want to serialize it or not.

So as an example, if you have a field `Address` that is not present in `PropertyInfo`, set the property `ShouldSerializeAddress` to false and the XmlSerializer should ignore it.

[Check this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553828/how-can-i-ignore-properties-according-to-their-value-with-xmlserializer).